# The method dispose () is undefined for the type new ActionListener(){}

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to make it so that my jframe is closed once the user presses login. However, it does not let me dispose the login window. Please help me. thank you.

```
JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
    btnLogin.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
             
            
            String password = txtPassword.getText();
            String username = txtUsername.getText();
            
            if (password.contains("Marvel")&& username.contains("KingSlayer")) {
                txtPassword.setText(null);
                txtUsername.setText(null);
                
                {
                    
                 Main_menu info = new Main_menu();
                 
                 info.setVisible(true);
                 dispose();
                 
                }
```

Comment: The context of the call to `dispose()` is the new anonymous subclass of `ActionListener` you are creating. So you're actually calling the `dispose` method of your `ActionListener` – which I doubt whether it exists. To call `dispose()` on the *outer* class, use `OuterClass.this.dispose()`.

Comment: I tried OuterClass.this.dispose(); it didnt work,

Comment: it says "Outerclass cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: Of course, you need to use the actual (top-level) class name you're using, instead of literally "OuterClass". But you haven't shown us your whole code.

Comment: I have used the name, there are no errors now. However, when I press run and login, it still doesn't dispose.

Comment: How do you know the code is executed? Did you add to println() statement to verify that your if statement is executed?

Answer (score 1):

I like to use generic code so I don't need to know the name of any of the classes involved.

In the `ActionListener` you can use code like:

```
JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(button).dispose();
```

The above code will get a reference to the window containing the button that was clicked so you can invoke the dispose() method.